# GetElementById vs Dom iteration

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript

Say I have small a list of IDs (about 10) and I would like to fetch the corresponding elements in an Html page.

Should I use getElementbyId() on each ID, or could I iterate through the DOM like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    var childNode = <HTMLElement>element.childNodes[i];

    if (this.Ids.indexOf(node.id, 0) >= 0)
            this.collection.setValue(node.id, <HTMLInputElement>node)

    if (childNode.childNodes.length > 0)
        this.iterateHtmlNodes(task, childNode);
}
```

- Which is the fastest way to do this ?
- Which is the best way ?
- What if I have a greater number of elements to fetch (>100) ?

I'm using TypeScript.

Comment: iterating is madness! `getElementById` is one single function call to a native method. It will be a dozen times faster than looping manually.

Comment: Not so fast... Although I *think* getElementById will be highly-optimized by all browsers, it would require actual testing to say for certain that it is faster than the loop.  JavaScript loops are highly optimized by most engines these days.  It could be true that both are similar in speed for small number of elements and flat DOM trees.

Comment: Check out this test I made: [link](http://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-iteration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any case using `GetElementById` will be faster as in browsers it uses native function support.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way depends on the implementation of the underlying JS/Typescript engine, so you would need to do some benchmarking and see the results.

If the document to be parsed complies with id uniqueness I would go with the `getElementById` approach. In a real-world document you might need to use your iteration approach, but be careful about unexpected results if there is more than one element with the same identifier.

Also, "best" implies some subjectiveness, so I would go for code clarity and use the `getElementById` option.

Comment: My page complies with id uniqueness, so no problem using it. Thanks